# How do I get my TableView selection to open my modal view?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I created a `TableView` with a `TableViewCell` in it.

I would like my cells in my `TableView` to open up in a separate `ViewController`.

My storyboard looks like this:

[image: my storyboard]

My `TableViewController` has this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowVerse" {
        let pageDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PageViewController

        // Get the cell that generated this segue.
        if let selectedPageCell = sender as? PageTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedPageCell)!
            let selectedPage = pages[indexPath.row]
            pageDetailViewController.page = selectedPage
        }
    }
}
```

And in my **PageViewController.swift** I have this :

```
var page: Page?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let page = page {
        chapter.text = String(page.chapter)
        verse.text = String(page.verse)
    }
}
```

I do not get any errors. But tapping the cells does not nothing. What might I be missing?

Comment: connect segue from table cell to detailvc not from tablevc to detailvc

Comment: @TejasArdeshna I thought that's what I did. I ctrl+dragged from the tableViewCell to the DetailViewCell to produce the above picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowVerse", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Would I then pass all my variables within this method instead of doing it in `prepareForSegue` ?

Comment: No you should stick with your approach unfortunately

Comment: You could also do it directly from storyboard. Select tableviewcell from connection inspector->triggered segues drag from selection to your view controller. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**

code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("homeSegue", sender: self)
```

Before switching to next view controller, if you wants to pass value to next view controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "homeSegue")
    {
        var homeController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController
        homeController.name = "valeu"
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowVerse" sender:self];
```

Before switching to next view controller, if you wants to pass value to next view controller

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowVerse"]) {
    HomeViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.propertyName = @"value";
}
}
```

Comment: Is that swift? And what would be technically different about how I'm passing value to my next controller with what I have already?

Comment: It is for objective-C. No issue i would post for swift also.

Comment: Ah your answer is super helpful. But unfortunately, it returns `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`  for the `homeController.name = "value"` line. But that response wouldn't be as dynamic as mine either since I want to carry the dynamic vars from my Cell over to it

Comment: Hey Trip, actually 'name' take place of your property that does exists in your  next/destination view controller.